# Show count value and multiple row in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I did try to get the answer myself by googling it but i can't find the solution.

I've two table actually.

This is suppose students table

```
id  | sname | cid
 1      a      1
 2      b      2
 3      c      2
 4      d      3
 5      e      4
 6      f      3
 7      g      4
 8      h      3
```

This is the class table

```
id  | sname 
 1      c1    
 2      c2    
 3      c3    
 4      c4
```

I want the result like below:

```
Result:

id  | cname | sname | count
 1      c1      a       1
 2      c2      b       2
 3      c2      c       2
 4      c3      d       3
 1      c4      e       2
 2      c3      f       3
 3      c4      g       2
 4      c3      h       3
```

As you can see the result will be like the above all the student name would be show alongside with class name & count would be like that.

How can I do this ?

Comment: what is `id` and `count` id of what? count of what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM
((SELECT C.id,C.sname as cname,S.sname as sname
FROM class C INNER JOIN students S on C.id=S.cid) T1
LEFT JOIN
(Select C.id,count(S.cid) as count
FROM class C INNER JOIN students S on C.id=S.cid
GROUP BY C.id) T2 on T2.id=T1.id)
ORDER BY sname
```

Result:

```
ID  CNAME   SNAME   COUNT
1   c1      a       1
2   c2      b       2
2   c2      c       2
3   c3      d       3
4   c4      e       2
3   c3      f       3
4   c4      g       2
3   c3      h       3
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ba176/18).

**Explanation:**

First part of the inner query selects id,cname and sname. Second part selects the count. And in outer query, we just join them.

Comment: it works... lots of thanks .. but as my reputation is lower than 15 I can't vote your answer up... sorry for that... but still many many thanks for saving my day ...

Answer (score 0):

A join with a subquery for count should do:

```
SELECT
    s.id `id`,
    c.sname `cname`,
    s.sname `sname`,
    (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM students WHERE students.cid = c.id) `count`
FROM
    students s
    LEFT JOIN class c ON s.cid = s.id
```

Comment: the query is not working as I've wanted ... it's only showing count 1 that's it. I need to count the class id's on student table.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT S.ID AS ID , C.SNAME AS CNAME , S.SNAME AS SNAME , CNT.COUNT AS COUNT
 FROM STUDENTS S ,  CLASS C , (
                               SELECT S.CID AS CID , COUNT(*) AS COUNT
                               FROM STUDENTS S
                               GROUP BY S.CID
                               ) AS CNT

 WHERE S.CID = C.ID AND CNT.CID = C.ID
```